# Программа которая обнаруживает пропуски в названиях программ

Tags: python, файлы

Есть папка, в которой есть файлы spam001, spam002 и так далее. Если например spam003 отсутствует, нужно чтобы программа создала файл, что бы устранить пропуск.
Извините что нет кода, я новичок я не понимаю как это реализовать;(
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Получить список имён файлов в папке
2. Выделить из каждого элемента списка числа
3. Обойти список, на каждой итерации проверяя, что значение текущего элемента соответствует его порядковому номеру